# Multiple id selectors

Tags: javascript, selector

I have  a form with 2 drop down lists on the same page using the same ids.

```
<select id="country">
  <option value="">Any</option>
  <option value="ENGLAND">England</option>
  <option value="IRELAND">Ireland</option>
  <option value="SCOTLAND">Scotland</option>
  <option value="WALES">Wales</option>
</select>

<select id="county">
  <option value="">Select a country first...</option>
</select>

<div style="clear:both">&nbsp;</div>

<select id="country">
  <option value="">Any</option>
  <option value="ENGLAND">England</option>
  <option value="IRELAND">Ireland</option>
  <option value="SCOTLAND">Scotland</option>
  <option value="WALES">Wales</option>
</select>

<select id="county">
  <option value="">Select a country first...</option>
</select>
```

Not sure how to I change the  JavaScript code so the second county drop down list functions same as the first one. The existing javascript and how it functions can be seen here:

http://jsfiddle.net/pfYEb/10/

Comment: IDs must be unique on a page. Use a class instead of an ID.

Comment: "using the same ids."  Stop there.  Go back.  Correct it.  You can't have more than one element with the same ID in the same document at the same time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll probably want to use class="country" instead of id="country" so that your selector will match both.  (same for your id="county")  In your jsfiddle, you'll also need to distinguish which county to change within your country change event.  One easy way to do this is to use the index of the current element.

I've forked your jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/wYswj/).

**HTML**

```
<select class="country">
  <option value="">Any</option>
  <option value="ENGLAND">England</option>
  <option value="IRELAND">Ireland</option>
  <option value="SCOTLAND">Scotland</option>
  <option value="WALES">Wales</option>
</select>

<select class="county">
  <option value="">Select a country first...</option>
</select>

<div style="clear:both">&nbsp;</div>

<select class="country">
  <option value="">Any</option>
  <option value="ENGLAND">England</option>
  <option value="IRELAND">Ireland</option>
  <option value="SCOTLAND">Scotland</option>
  <option value="WALES">Wales</option>
</select>

<select class="county">
  <option value="">Select a country first...</option>
</select>
​
```

**Relevant Javascript:**

```
  $('.country').change(function() {
    var country = $(this).val(),
        county  = $('.county').eq($(".country").index(this)); // This matches the county

    // Empty county dropdown
    county.empty();

    // Update dropdown with appropriate contents
    if (country === '') {
      county.append('<option value="">Select a country first...</option>');
    } else {
      $.each(counties[country], function(i, v) {
        county.append('<option value="' + i + '">' + v + '</option>');  
      });
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't really solve this querying by *id*. Element ID's have to be unique within a document by specification by the way. Your best shot, use `classes` instead.